# In JavaScript, How can I access properties of children nodes?

Tags: javascript, node.js, dom, phantomjs, casperjs

I'm building a link **scraper** in CasperJS, and the main functions looks pretty much like this:

```
function findLinks() {
    return Array.prototype.map.call(document.querySelectorAll('a'), function(e){
        return { 
                 href: e.href,
                 title: e.title, 
                 rel: e.rel, 
                 anchor: e.text,
                 innerHTML: e.innerHTML
               };
    });
}
```

However, I'd like to modify `findLinks()` in a way that if my link **scraper** finds something like this:

`<a href="#" title="anchor tag" rel="nofollow"><img src="myimage.jpg" alt="beautiful image" /></a>`

I can access `<img>` attributes individually, just as I do it with the links.

I've been reading Mozilla MDN, and CasperJS and I haven't found yet a way to achieve this,

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for [`Element.children`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.children)

> *children* returns a collection of child elements of the given element.

In your example HTML:

```
var b = document.querySelectorAll('a')[0];
alert(b.children[0].src); //First child's source: myimage.jpg
```

[(fiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/jVZ9W/)

Answer (score 0):

Document Object Model (DOM) API is what you are looking for.
Here is the site that I find useful for  [DOM documentation](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_node.asp)

in your instance `e.childNodes[n].attributes['href']` would be an example.

But, better yet, if you are using extreme html tree traversing, my suggestion is to use jQuery. It is made exactly for your purpose.